# Android App throwing FileNotFoundException after uninstalling and reinstalling

Tags: java, android, android-studio, filenotfoundexception

I have been working on a small app on android studio that requires accessing a file to read and write passwords. When I was first testing it it worked fine, but when I uninstalled the app, and reinstalled it using the apk, It throws a `FileNotFound` Exception in MainActivity, at the first time I try to access the file. This is the code I use in MainActivity.java:

```
                File fh = new File(getFilesDir().getPath(),"nothinghere.txt");
                Log.d("FileHandling","file exists "+fh.exists()+" file is directory "+ fh.isDirectory()+" file can be read "+fh.canRead()+" path "+fh.getAbsolutePath());
                try {
                    Log.d("FileHandling","Initializing InputStream");
                    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fh);
                    Log.d("FileHandling","InputStream success");
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    Log.d("FileHandling","BufferedReader success");
                    String password=reader.readLine();
                    Log.d("FileHandling","readLine success");
                    if(password==null){
                        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreatePass.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnterPass.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                    Log.d("FileHandling","File Not Found when retrieving password");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("FileHandling","IOException when retrieving password");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I have a lot of Logs from trying to debug it. The exception occurs at `InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fh);`. I commented all this code out, and had MainActivity start another activity where I access the same file, and that activity worked fine as well, until I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it(this time using android studio Run App not the apk) and I had the same problem with that activity then.
[This is the folder where my java classes are in, and the txt file I access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Bov.png) they are all in the same folder.
This is the error I get.

```
2020-06-04 19:46:32.156 17982-17982/com.example.calculator W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.calculator/files/nothinghere.txt (No such file or directory)
2020-06-04 19:46:32.156 17982-17982/com.example.calculator W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
2020-06-04 19:46:32.156 17982-17982/com.example.calculator W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
2020-06-04 19:46:32.156 17982-17982/com.example.calculator W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
```

I think it's also relevant, that after the first time the error occurred sometimes I would get this warning when applying changes:

```
Changes were not applied.
We were unable to deploy your changes: SETUP_FAILED
```

Also, when I then tried to uncomment the lines on MainActivity to access the file, it still throws the same exception and error. This is a very strange problem, I don't have a lot of experience with working with android and I can not find anything that decribes my problem, so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: "This is the folder where my java classes are in, and the txt file I access"  -- that is on your development machine. Those text files are not on the device as files on the filesystem, unless you take steps to copy them there.

Comment: I tried putting them in res/raw but I'm not sure what the relative path is that I can use for the File constructor.

Comment: Again, they are not files on the device. If you put them in `res/raw`, you can call `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nothinghere)` on your `Activity` to give you an `InputStream` on the resource.